# Is it possible to recover initial weights from Keras model?

Tags: keras

I've trained basic model from `keras.Sequential` class but didn't save weights right after running `model.compile()`. Is it possible to recover initial weights from fitted model object? I checked `model.__dict__` and found there `'_initial_weights': None` but I don't get why, it is after a few epochs of training.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to recover the initial weights of your model from the fitted model object if you didn't save them right after compiling the model. The '_initial_weights': None in the model's dictionary confirms that there were no initial weights saved. However, you could try training the model again with a small number of epochs and then save the weights after the first epoch. You could then use these initial weights to initialize your original model and continue training from there.